# How to choose what to display in a ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What if I request the URL http://www.google.com via AJAX, for example and in the `on success`function I just wanted to display the *I'm feeling lucky* button in some div?

For example

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'www.google.com',
    success: function(html) {
        $('div').html(html);
    }
});
```

this is for displaying the whole page, but I want only to display the button. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a div around the button like:

```
<div id='button'><button>blah</button</div>
```

and the Ajax URL would be something like:

```
url: 'www.google.com #button',
```

Just add the selector to the end of the URL and it will return only that content.

Comment: Yes.  It's also documented in the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'www.google.com', 
    success: function(html) { 
        $('div').html($(html).find('input[name=btnI]')); 
    } 
});
```

You can replace `input[name=btnI]` with your own condition.